# RPC server is unavailable while configuring sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I tried to install SP2010 on my system which it has this situation:

I joined the domain with wifi and I'm installing SP2010 on a VMware workstation. I installed it and everything went well but when I go to my Sharepoint page in IE and want to configure it I ran into this error:

> RPC SERVER IS UNAVAILABLE

I checked it but its running now. What should I do to solve this problem and can continue configuration?

Answer (score 0):

```
ipconfig /flushdns 
ipconfig /registerdns
```